# How can I access private property of BigQuery\Timestamp

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery but I have a problem when I retrieve data. I have a BigQuery\Timestamp object

```
object(Google\Cloud\BigQuery\Timestamp)#1377 (1) { ["value":"Google\Cloud\BigQuery\Timestamp":private]=> object(DateTime)#1375 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2020-12-09 16:16:56.706000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+00:00" } }
```

The `value` property is `private` so I cannot use the date. I get this error message:

```
Cannot access private property Google\Cloud\BigQuery\Timestamp::$value
```

How can I get the string value of the `date` property ?
I need to sort all the data from two bigQuery datasets. The date is the key element and I want to have a result structured as follow

```
{
    "data": {
        "2020-12-12 12:00:00": {
            "data1_from_datasetA": 1,
            "data2_from_datasetA": 2,
            "data1_from_datasetB": 3,
        },
        "2020-12-12 13:00:00": {
            "data1_from_datasetA": 6,
            "data2_from_datasetA": 5,
            "data1_from_datasetB": 8,
        },
        "2020-12-12 14:00:00": {
            "data1_from_datasetA": 12,
            "data2_from_datasetA": 2,
            "data1_from_datasetB": 6,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: [The class](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-bigquery/blob/master/src/Timestamp.php) looks like it has a `get()` method - have you tried that? It returns the DateTime instance, you'll need to format it yourself.

Comment: I have a `foreach ($queryResults as $row)` in which I make a `var_dump($row["created_at"].get());`. I get a `Call to undefined function`.

Comment: `.` is the concatenation operator, you need `$row["created_at"]->get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [iainn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4680018/iainn) in the comment, using the get method of the class works perfectly.

```
$dateTime = $row["created_at"]->get()->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend asking for `rawResults` that don't turn timestamps into objects, as that is counter productive.

```
 $queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery($jobConfig, array(
            'timeoutMs' => 55 * 10000,
            'returnRawResults' => true
        ));
```

This way each entry is returned as a simple plain value.